# SQL Formatting: Add Space within query result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to insert a space into result set from a query, I tried using the space() function and right but I have confused myself.

The Column result from the query is:

- 1234567891234567891

I need this:

- 1234 567891234567891 (With a space after the 4th number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this several ways. I'm assuming this is stored as a number and not a string, and I'm using RTRIM to prevent invalid datatype errors.

```
DECLARE @i BIGINT = 1234567891234567891

SELECT LEFT(@i, 4) + ' ' + RIGHT(@i, LEN(@i) -4) AS lefty_righty

SELECT SUBSTRING(RTRIM(@i), 0, 5) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(RTRIM(@i), 5, LEN(@i)) AS substrings

SELECT STUFF(RTRIM(@i), 5, 0, ' ') AS stuffy
```